# Querying Two Wordpress Categories via URL

Tags: wordpress, url, parameters

I have posts that are assigned to two categories let's say cars and paints. I'm trying to only get posts that are in both, the following code `http://example.com/category/cars+paints` is supposed to work according to [this article](https://benohead.com/blog/2015/02/10/wordpress-menu-items-combining-multiple-categories/) but it doesn't and I get a page saying `The requested document was not found on this server.` When I try `http://exapmle.com/category/cars,paints` it works but it gives me too many posts.

It seems that `&` is supposed to work as well, I tried `http://exapmle.com/category/cars&paints` and `http://exapmle.com/category/?cat=cars&cat=paints` but this doesn't either work, I don't know if I have the syntax wrong.

When I try `http://exapmle.com/?cat=1&cat=2` using the category IDs it directs to a page like this `http://exapmle.com/category/paints` with the last parameter corresponding to the last number entered in the URL.

Does anyone know why it's not working and what I can do to get it to work, thanks in advance.

Comment: With seperating the terms with a comma, you are getting all posts that have either one of this terms, but not limited by to have both. Seperating with a plus must be defined in a function to work.

Comment: Thanks @rank, which function would I need to run and is it possible for me to run it from the custom link section in the built in wordpress menu.

Comment: Do you have pretty permalinks enabled ?

Comment: @shazyriver Yes

Comment: And have you double-checked your category slugs? `http://example.com/category/cars+paints` works for me using pretty permalinks

Comment: Yes, if I use a ```+``` it doesn't work but it I use the same slug with a ```,``` it works so the slugs are correct but for some reason it's not working. I wonder why it's working for you and not me

Comment: I tested it on two different site ( not mine ), one being https://www.starwars.com/. Probably you have a theme or plugin conflict if nothing else.

Comment: Thanks, I'll look into that but do you know of any code I can use to override a theme or plugin if they are causing the issue

Comment: It seems like all wordpress sites hosted by my work get this error ```Not Found
The requested document was not found on this server.``` when I use a ```+``` is it possible/ make sense that it's being blocked on the server and if yes is there a way to override it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Changing the `+` to a space `%20` seems to be working for me

Example:
`http://example.com/category/cars%20paints`